# Rails 3.1 Engines: How to call a script in /scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I'm refactoring a Rails app into an engine. The app relies on a python script in /script which I want to include with the engine.

The original app code is:

```
system("python #{Rails.root}/script/big_calculation.py")
```

Where should this script be stored in the new engine? How will I rewrite the above line of code to reflect this new location?

Thanks

Jack

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a `Rails.root` *per sé* in the engine. But you could make one by defining a constant in your engine like this:

```
module YourThing
  class Engine
    def self.root
      File.expand_path("../..")
    end
  end
end
```

Then you call it using `YourThing::Engine.root`.

Comment: As I was testing this out it turned out it was already built in. Thanks for the inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can just call

```
MyEngine::Engine.root
```

already.